# What is a "hypergeometric series" with differences, not just sums, of indices?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

"Hypergeometric series" often have forms like (in two variables)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_1)_n (a_2)_n}{(b_1)_k (c_1)_{n+k}} \frac{x^n}{n!} \frac{y^k}{k!}$$

And there are functions defined by these series that are used to represent their sums. But why don't there seem to be any functions for a series like

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_1)_n (a_2)_n}{(b_1)_k (c_1)_{n-k}} \frac{x^n}{n!} \frac{y^k}{k!}$$

which is essentially just like the first series but with a simple sign change? Is there a "hypergeometric function" that can express the sum of the latter series?

Comment: The last expression makes no sense for $n<k$.

Comment: @Lucian Why doesn't it make sense? Because of the Pochhammer symbol with negative index? Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see why that's not allowed.

Comment: @David H. Right. Provided that $c_1$ is not an integer, it extends naturally by repeated division. And if $c_1$ is an integer, you can consider the reciprocal of the Pochhammer symbol to be zero by the limit.

Comment: @DavidH: To [my](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) knowledge, there is [no](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) convention for such [notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RisingFactorial.html).

Comment: @Lucian: Well, OK, so what if you limit the upper index to $n$?